# Can I Use a BlowGun on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha

Would using something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006M9OFCC) constitute a violation of a Rabbinic or Torah Halacha?

If I am in my backyard and have an eruv, as long as I dont hit an animal, shouldn't it be ok? What about a foam target?

Thanks all!

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8636/3

Comment: One possible melacha, perhaps. I gather that when the dart lands, it bores a hole somewhere. The other idea is that this seems to be a device that shoots a venom dart which means that its main purpose is for hunting. Thus, it may considered muktzah on Shabbat, as hunting is forbidden on Shabbat, and what purpose does it have, otherwise?

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that any resultant hole be purely destructive and in no way constructive? And it's indirect. You're just shooting darts for fun or target, etc. So shouldn't that make it ok, since you are not boring a hole for a reason? Also the hold is in a foam, let's say, not in the ground...

Comment: @WAF 
There doesn't seem to be a clear answer, although some of the comments are interesting. Still wondering about this scenario, and if the indirectness of blowing it changes anything as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's just some related content that wasn't linked automatically. It would really enrich and differentiate this question if you delineated what you think are the concerns (the way you listed implicitly what aren't the concerns, like maiming animals and ha'avara).

Comment: That's the issue. I'm not really sure what other concerns there should be, other than, perhaps, it not being in the "spirit of shabbos."